# Prove continuity of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, nonstandard-analysis

> Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 \ \ \ \ 1 \le |x| \\ 1/n \ \ \ \ 1/n \le |x| \lt 1/(n-1), \ \ n \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } n \ge 2 \\ 0  \ \ \ \ x = 0\end{cases}$$
>   Prove that $f$ is continuous at $x= 0$ but discontinuous at $x = \pm 1/n$

---

Let $f^*$ be a hyperreal extension of $f$.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} f^*(x) = st(f^*(|\varepsilon|))$$

Now for any infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ we can find a infinite hyperinteger $K$ such that $${1\over K} \le |\varepsilon| \lt {1\over K-1}$$

Therefore $$ f^*(|\varepsilon|) = {1\over K} = \delta$$
Since $ \lim_{x \to c} f(c) = st(f^*(c))$
$$\therefore \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = st(f^*(\varepsilon)) = st(\delta) = 0  = f(0)$$

Hence $f$ continous at $0$.

Similarly,

$$\lim_{x \to 1/n} f^*(x) = st(f^*(1/n + \epsilon))$$

Let $n$ be a infinite hyperinterger $H$,

$$f^*(1/H + \varepsilon) = f^*(\delta + \epsilon)$$

Like the proof above we can find a $J$ such that $\displaystyle {1\over J} \le |\delta + \epsilon| \le {1\over J- 1}$

$$\therefore st(f^*(\delta + \epsilon)) = st\left({1\over J}\right) \ne {1\over H} = f^*(1/ H)$$

Therefore $f^*$ is discontinuous at $\pm 1/n$ and therefore $f$ is also discontinuous.

---

- I getting a feeling like I have used too many symbols that mean nothing and my proof is wrong. I think the second part is probably is wrong. Please tell me if this proof is correct and if not then how to correct it ?

Comment: Do you need to use nonstandard analysis? The problem is perfectly feasible without it.

Comment: You seem to have some basic misunderstandings. $f(a) = f^*(a)$ for every standard real $a$, and for every nonzero infinitesimal $\epsilon$, $$\lim_{x \to 0} f^*(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \operatorname{st}(f^*(\epsilon))$$ (where the limit on the left is the internal limit)

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes I was a bit confused, thanks. I have edited the question. Can you check if there are anymore errors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second part is incorrect.  You need to prove discontinuity at $1/n$ for a *fixed* standard $n$, so it makes no sense to "let $n$ be $H$" as you do here. Here it suffices to point out that for any infinitesimal $\epsilon>0$ you will have $f(\frac{1}{n}-\epsilon)=\frac{1}{n+1}$ which is *not* infinitely close to $\frac{1}{n}$ and therefore the function is discontinuous at $x=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I used $H$ because If I can prove discontinuity for a integer then no need to prove for all of them, right ?

Comment: Well apriori continuity at $c$ is defined for *real* $c$ only, i.e., standard $n$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

- $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$ by taking $n\epsilon<1$.
- $\lim_{x\to\frac1n^+}f(x)=\frac1n$ but $\lim_{x\to\frac1n^-}f(x)=\frac1{n+1}$ on the piecewise constant function.